# Com.android.systemui

Tags: samsung

Ok so I have a samsung galixy note 0.8 and whenever I hold the home button to see what tabs are open a message comes up saying that my com.android.systemui is not responding. My screen goes black for a second but I can still see my apps.  Then it shuts off and turns back on. This started yesterday.

Comment: We need more informaation to answer this,

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89253/how-to-fix-instant-lock-unfortunately-com-android-systemui-has-stopped-on-moto

Answer (score 0):

I had the same on my Samsung Note, I deleted google from my Note and that's the trick. Google probably needs to fix a bug in the last update, but until now it is not fixed yet.

[image: This app see in the link below]

Answer (score 0):

same for me on my Note 8.0

rolling back Google App fixes it but even though I have disabled auto updates at PlayStore it still then reupdates and re-occurs.
Interestingly this only happens when the device is in Portrait orientation. When it is in Landscape it is fine

Note 8.0 GT-N5120
Android 4.4.2
Baseband N5120XXDNE4

Google App 6.10.37.16.arm